# SolutionEvents for Visual studio 2010 addin does not fire

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm building an visual studio 2010 addin and trying to hook into an event when the solution is loaded.

Basically what I have found is that SolutionEvents.Opened seems to be what I'm looking for, however listening to it in OnConnection does not seem to be working:

```
public void OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref Array custom)
{
  applicationObject = (DTE2)application;
  var outputWindow = (OutputWindow)applicationObject.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindOutput).Object;
  outputWindowPane = outputWindow.OutputWindowPanes.Add("My Pane");
  applicationObject.Events.SolutionEvents.Opened += SolutionEventsOnOpened;
  outputWindowPane.OutputString("Connected");
}

private void SolutionEventsOnOpened()
{
  outputWindowPane.OutputString("SolutionEventsOnOpened");
}
```

The only thing outputed is "Connected".

I have tried to listen to SolutionItemsEvents.ItemAdded and SolutionEvents.ProjectAdded and also they do not fire.

Should I init the events elsewhere? (Note I have R# installed, perhaps it is knowed to cause issues?)

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution here: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/kolbis/archive/2007/11/22/hooking-up-to-the-solution-events.aspx

Basically, you need to declare members at your add-in class scope for the SolutionEvents and Events variables, and assign them, and then reference the eventhandlers through that. E.g.

```
    private Events2 m_events;
    private SolutionEvents m_solutionEvents;
```

then in the OnConnection handler (when your plugin gets initialised) do this:

```
    m_application = Application as DTE2;

    m_events = (Events2)m_application.Events;
    m_solutionEvents = m_events.SolutionEvents;
```

and finally, wire up the solution Opened/AfterClosing events, as follows:

```
    m_solutionEvents.Opened += m_openSolution;
    m_solutionEvents.AfterClosing += m_closeSolution;
```

Then the events will fire.

I presume the reason for doing this is because otherwise the Events/SolutionEvents objects get changed or GC'd (or both ;-).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

With VS2010, when opening a .sln file that leads to start a new VS2010 instance, it is worth noting that `SolutionEvents.Opened` is fired **before** `EventsObj.OnStartupComplete` is fired. So if you register `SolutionEvents.Opened` during `EventsObj.OnStartupComplete` it won't fire in this situation.

As far as I know all VS versions post-2010 [2012-2019] fire `SolutionEvents.Opened` **after** `EventsObj.OnStartupComplete` is fired.